# Any chance of speeding up this simple MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

Stumped on this query, it searches an important table which contains about 213k rows. The purpose of the query is to report traffic data for a month. The amount of traffic for each day of that month. And sum of a decimal value for each day. This query is ran frequently so I need to optimize it to the best possible. Currently takes avg. 2 seconds..

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/171f5/3/0

All suggestions will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**Query:**

```
SELECT `date_day`, COUNT(*) AS num, SUM(decval) AS sum_decval FROM (`tbl_traffic`)
WHERE `uuid` = '1' AND `date_year` = '2012' AND `date_month` = '11'
GROUP BY `date_day`;
```

**Explain Result:**

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: adb1_analytics
type: ref
possible_keys: keys1,keys2,keys3
key: keys1
key_len: 7
ref: const,const,const
rows: 106693
Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.13 sec)
```

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_traffic` (
  `id` int(100) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` int(100) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` char(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `referrer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `decval` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL,
  `date_year` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_month` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_day` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `keys1` (`uuid`,`date_year`,`date_month`,`date_day`),
  KEY `keys2` (`date_year`,`date_month`,`referrer`),
  KEY `keys3` (`date_year`,`date_month`,`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use count(id) and add keys on date_day and decval.
A covering key over both fields might be even better

Comment: @stov01, I agree with Michel, if you add decval as part of the index, it can get all values directly from the index and NOT require going to the raw data row, so a full index by (uuid, date_year, date_month, date_day, decval) would be your best bet.

Comment: count(id) made no difference, however, the full index did the trick.. I tried that before and it didn't work. Tried again, didn't work.. But after performing an ANALYZE TABLE, it seemed to do the trick! Now shaved down from avg 2sec to 0.4sec, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have no effective indexes on `date_day`.

I would recommend creating a key specifically for what you are fetching and calculating: `(date_day, decval)`

Comment: For my edification, using int(100) rather than bigint have an impact on performance?

Comment: @rontornambe [Initial research](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=13825) shows there is slight performance over `bigint`.

Comment: @stov01 Start with the fundamentals. See what happens when you remove the aggregates.. the filter...

Comment: This worked in collaboration with Michel Feldheim & DRapp's comment. And also learned a trick from this for optimizing some of my other queries as well. Thank you for you input!

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you do a 'group by' you're asking for a full table scan.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

If you can't index it better (see @njk answer) then you might want to select for your specific values then do the group, sum, etc on the sub set. If nothing else, at least it will be a smaller set to sort.

Comment: My initial reaction is that a derived table would not help.

Comment: Possibly not. Solving this would take some experimentation.